# Is there a way to avoid jboss-serialization in JBoss5?

Tags: java, serialization, jboss, jboss5.x

I have 2 apps running in JBoss5.

They send data to each other. I added a field to one of the `Serializable` classes without changing `serialVersionUID`. This class is still backward compatible according to [Java serialization rules](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-5things1/).

The problem I'm facing is that JBoss throws an IOException whenever I try to send it over an EJB call from one app to the other:

```
java.io.IOException: Current classpath has lesser fields on com.myproject.MyEntity than its original version
    org.jboss.serial.classmetamodel.StreamingClass.readStream(StreamingClass.java:98)
    org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.ObjectDescriptorFactory.readObjectDescriptionFromStreaming(ObjectDescriptorFactory.java:381)
    org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.ObjectDescriptorFactory.objectFromDescription(ObjectDescriptorFactory.java:82)
    org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.DataContainer$DataContainerInput.readObject(DataContainer.java:845)
    org.jboss.serial.io.MarshalledObjectForLocalCalls.get(MarshalledObjectForLocalCalls.java:60)
    org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invokeLocal(IsLocalInterceptor.java:101)
    org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:72)
    org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    org.jboss.aspects.remoting.PojiProxy.invoke(PojiProxy.java:62)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy881.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:207)
    org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:164)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1063.getAlertScheduleForTrip(Unknown Source)
    com.myclient.ejb.MyEntityLoadingBean.loadMyEntities(MyEntityLoadingBean.java:256)
    ...
```

Is there any way to tell JBoss to avoid using it's serialization module and use standard Java serialization instead? This bug appears to be known and in the JBoss JIRA for a few years now: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBSER-120

I've tried starting JBoss with `-Dserialization.jboss=false` but that didn't work (I think that may only work with the JBoss Cache).

Comment: This message sounds like your lib on the client side is not updated ...

Comment: The libs are updated *enough*. They are not identical, but they *are* backward compatible per the Java serialization rules (as stated in the question). The issue is broken jboss serialization. Hence the question: How to avoid using the broken JBoss serialization?